# Null pointer exception in setting font in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I am encountering some issue while trying to set font for drawing string function in Java.
My goal is to draw something on image using function `drawString(text, posLeft, posTop);` where `text` is the string, and `posLeft` and `posTop` are positions of it from left and top of the screen.
In that purpose i have following code:

```
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(image);       
            
        image.getGraphics().setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, size));
        image.getGraphics().setColor(c);
        image.getGraphics().drawString(text, posLeft, posTop);
        
        image.getGraphics().dispose();
```

where `image` is instance of `java.awt.BufferedImage` class object, `icon` is instance of `javax.swing.Icon` with constructor of class `javax.swing.ImageIcon.ImageIcon(Image image)`. Font is of the class `java.awt.Font`.
Then i'm getting graphics with `image.getGraphics()`, however null pointer exception occurs while trying to set font part, in line `image.getGraphics().setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, size));` .
The error message is only `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`. I tried changing font but it is still the same.
Would very appreciate any help regarding this!
(hope i didn't miss some important part)
Both image and image.getGraphics() are working, since i checked it in the code and got following:

```
BufferedImage@3c52b5ae: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@35069130 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 659 height = 587 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
----
sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D[font=java.awt.Font[family=Dialog,name=Dialog,style=plain,size=12],color=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]]
----
```

where first part above`---` is `image`, and later is `image.getGraphics()`.
Also, I tried using `Font f=new Font('Arial',Font.BOLD,size)`, and there i firstly got null pointer exception and some null value occurring there.

Comment: Looks like `image.getGraphics()` is `null`. Have you checked it ?

Comment: Could someone perhaps reopen the question, i changed tag, and added additional details.

Comment: It's still incomplete. You need a minimal reproducible example. Are you saying `Font f=new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,size)` is enough to cause an NPE?

Comment: For example, http://pastie.org/p/5yFYLP66FRs2jK7MdMIinw this is a minimal example with all of the relevant bits from your post. It works fine for me.

Comment: Also, is `size` an Integer? If it is an Integer, then it can be null and you'll get an NPE when auto-unboxing occurs.

Comment: @matt It seems that to me.  
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.println(image);
        System.out.println("----");
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, size);           
        System.out.println(font);
        System.out.println("----"); Here everything is printed and line Font font= new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,size) throws the null pointer exception. Size is int primitive type.

Comment: @slomil try printing out `size`

Comment: Thank you man.. i had many different methods where i called this function, and in one place i had null value..